# Is there any url regex validator that fits this criteria?

Tags: regex

I need a url validator regex with this criteria:

- protocol (HTTP, HTTPS) is optional. *But* if any protocol is given, it must be in the correct format, i.e. protocol:domain, or protocol://domain.
- www is optional
- it's possible to use direct IP address for this.

So based on the criteria, these should pass:

- http://www.google.com
- google.com
- abc.def.ghi/hij
- https:216.239.38.120
- 216.239.38.120

These should not pass:

- hello
- hello/world
- abc://def.ghi
- ftp:google.com

The closest regex I've found is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70565103):

```
^((?:.|\n)*?)((http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:‌​,.;]*)?)
```

But unfortunately, `google.com` doesn't pass. It needs to have `www.` as a prefix. Can you improve this regex so `www.` becomes optional?

Comment: Maybe something like `^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|https:(?:\/\/)?)?\w+(?:[-.]\w+)+(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*$` will be enough? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ibx3ED/2).

Comment: "*But unfortunately, google.com doesn't pass. It needs to have www. as a prefix.*" [it seems to work for "google.com"](https://regex101.com/r/lUkKoJ/1). I mean it's horrible but it does match it. I chose the Python flavour only because for PHP/JS the pattern is wrong (unescaped forward slashes) and I didn't want to change them.

Comment: Do you really need this to be a regex-based solution, or are you asking an XY problem? Typically I would opt to solve this with a URL parsing library in the language of your choice, not a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works wonderfully! I'll use this. If you repost this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @TomLord but have you considered that using a library would be easier to implement and easier to maintain in the future, as well? It's almost as if you are trying to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following pattern matches your criteria:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|https:(?:\/\/)?)?\w+(?:[-.]\w+)+(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ibx3ED/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|https:(?:\/\/)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?` - `http` or `https`, `://` and then an optional `www.` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `https:(?:\/\/)?` - `https:` and then an optional `//` string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:[-.]\w+)+`- one or more sequences of a `.` or `-` followed with one or more word chars
- `(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*` - an optional sequence of a `/` an then one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace
- `$` -  end of string.