# Uri parse does not parse

Tags: dart

```dart
  String baseUrl = "httpswwwmywebsiteit";
  Uri primaUrl = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
  print(primaUrl); // returns httpswwwmywebsiteit
```

Is this a valid uri? How can I spot malformed urls? For example where having one slash instead of two? Or mispelled scheme?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart / Flutter - Validating a string for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975739/dart-flutter-validating-a-string-for-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `"httpswwwmywebsiteit"` is a valid URI Reference (according to [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.1)).

It's a relative-part with a path-noscheme which is just a single URI path segment.

If you want to validate that something is a valid URI, and has a scheme and path, you need to check for that.

```dart
if (!primaUrl.hasScheme || !primarUrl.hasAuthority || primaUrl.path.isEmpty) {
  // Or whichever requirements you have on the URI.
  throw ArgumentError.value(baseUrl, "baseUrl", "Not a full URI");
}
```

Checking whether the scheme is valid requires you to define what that means, then you can check that `primaUrl.scheme` satisfies that.

Answer (score 3):

[Irhn on "Uri.parse doesn't throw FormatException"](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34952#issuecomment-433804065)

> The Dart Uri class is not validating registered schemes, only the [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) grammar.
> The only special caseing offered by the Uri class is recognition of the default port for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

You should watch this: [Dart / Flutter - Validating a string for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975739/dart-flutter-validating-a-string-for-url)